# Open Photo Edit Picker from an app on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm working on a Lens app for Windows Phone, and have been trying to find an API for the [Photo Edit Picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202966(v=vs.105).aspx), but so far I'm unable to find one. From what I'm guessing, there doesn't seem to be a task to open the following screen in `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks` namespace.

Is there a way to open the Photo Edit Picker list from an app, or is that not supported?

[image]